# How to join those sql statements + possible row to column transformation

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, let say that I have those three tables (data is not logical).

**OWNERS**

```
ID_OWNER | NAME | SURNAME 
1    John    Carter
2    Chris   Collins
3    Wright   Doe
```

**CARS**

```
ID_OWNER | MODEL | MODEL_TYPE
1     |   FORD_FOCUS  |  FAMILY
1     |  TRANSPORTER_VW   |   TRANSPORTER
1     |   VOLVO_S60     | null
2     |    VOLVO_S80    |  null
```

**PRICE**

```
MODEL_TYPE| PRICE1
FAMILY | 2
TRANSPORTER | 4
```

So I have two SQL statements so far. The first one search for owner:

```
SELECT 
    o.NAME, o.SURNAME 
FROM
    OWNERS o 
WHERE
    o.NAME='John';
```

The second one search for model and price for owner 'John'. Because of possible null value of MODEL_TYPE I used LEFT JOIN. I got three rows.

```
SELECT
    CARS.ID_OWNER, CARS.MODEL, CARS.MODEL_TYPE, PRICE.PRICE1 
FROM
    CARS 
LEFT JOIN
    PRICE ON CARS.MODEL_TYPE = PRICE.MODEL_TYPE
WHERE
    CARS.ID_OWNER = 1;
```

**RESULT:**

```
ID_OWNER | MODEL          | MODEL_TYPE  | PRICE1 | NAME |SURNAME
    1    | FORD FOCUS     | FAMILY      |   2    | JOHN | CARTER
    1    | TRANSPORTER_VW | TRANSPORTER |   4    | JOHN | CARTER
    1    | VOLOV_S60      | null        | null   | JOHN | CARTER
```

Now I need results of all cars and their model type and price owned by John Carter in one row in one SQL query. I'm stuck.

Is it possible? I read about pivot and other possibilities but do not find appropriate answer. How to combine it and merge result in one row and not three?

Comment: so do you want dynamic number of columns?  are you sure? It's totally possible, but usually it's not very good idea to have dynamic number of columns. Or may be you want to concatenate all cars into one long string?

Comment: Problem is that I have pretty large database and because of efficient I would like to query only once and not twice.

Comment: I think querying once have nothing to do with pivoting - you can fetch all 3 rows to the client and then do whatever you want with it. From my experience, it's better to pivot your data on the client side, SQL is not very good working with dynamic number of columns.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no more than n cars for each person, you can do this:

```
with cte as (
    select
        o.NAME, o.SURNAME,
        c.MODEL,
        c.MODEL_TYPE,
        p.PRICE1,
        row_number() over(partition by o.ID_OWNER order by MODEL) as rn
    from OWNERS as o
        left outer join CARS as c on c.ID_OWNER = o.ID_OWNER
        left outer join PRICE as p on p.MODEL_TYPE = c.MODEL_TYPE
)
select
    c.NAME, c.SURNAME,
    max(case when c.rn = 1 then c.MODEL end) as MODEL1,
    max(case when c.rn = 1 then c.MODEL_TYPE end) as MODEL_TYPE1,
    max(case when c.rn = 1 then c.PRICE1 end) as PRICE11,
    max(case when c.rn = 2 then c.MODEL end) as MODEL2,
    max(case when c.rn = 2 then c.MODEL_TYPE end) as MODEL_TYPE2,
    max(case when c.rn = 2 then c.PRICE1 end) as PRICE12,
    max(case when c.rn = 3 then c.MODEL end) as MODEL3,
    max(case when c.rn = 3 then c.MODEL_TYPE end) as MODEL_TYPE3,
    max(case when c.rn = 3 then c.PRICE1 end) as PRICE13
from cte as c
group by c.NAME, c.SURNAME
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/002fa/3)</kbd>**

It's easy to do this as dynamic SQL for arbitrary number of cars, but I'm not sure you can use this query on the client side, it's usually easier to work with rows (not columns)